# Asynchronous WCF service blocks ASP application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, blocking

I have an ASP (MVC2) application that is calling a WCF Service.  The service is going to take a long time, so I don't want the client ASP application to wait for it to finish.  It records its status in the database, and that is available to the ASP client.
I am calling the service asynchronously, but my ASP application still hangs when it trys to transition to the next page.  I suspect it is because of the thread hanging waiting for the service to reply.
What is the best way to implement this interface so that the ASP application can continue and not be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to know result of web service call you don't need asynchronous call. You need one way (also known as fire and forget) call. Add `IsOneWay=true` to your `OperationContract` like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface MyServiceContract
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
  void MyOperation(Data data);
}
```

One way operation must return `void`. Client will only wait to estabilish connection and send data. It will not wait for end of processing.

Comment: As Ladislav stated, the client will only wait long enough to establish the connection and send the request but it still waits.  If you configure a long timeout on the client side and the server isn't responding, your ASP.NET thread will block up to the client timeout value. Thus, either configure your client timeout to be relatively short or spin off a new thread to make each call.

Comment: I didn't know about the oneway option.   I solved the problem a different way.  I started a new thread in the service and had it do the work.  Meanwhile, the thread that received the request returned at once to the client.  That separated the client from the service and let them proceed in parallel.